# Button Click event not working inside accordian pane

Tags: asp.net, button, accordion

I have a button in my accordian pane which genrates random Passwords and inserts the data in the database. but It's not working, even when I do debugging the control in not even going to CLick Event. my HTML Code i as 
   
         
        
        New User

```
    <asp:Button ID="genrate" runat="server" Text="Genrate passwords"  />
    </Content>
    </asp:AccordionPane></b>
```

the code behind is--- 
         public static string RandomStr()

```
{
    string rStr = Path.GetRandomFileName();
    rStr = rStr.Replace(".", ""); // For Removing the .
    return rStr;
}



    protected void genrate_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string rand = RandomStr();
        un.Text = rand;
        Uname.ReadOnly = true;
        string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ajax"].ConnectionString;
        string selectcomnd = "INSERT INTO user (username,password) as value(@e1,@e2)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = selectcomnd;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@e1", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = Uname.Text;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@e2", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = rand;
       con.Close();




    }
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: got the solution. i now it's working missing executenonquery and most important buttton click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing onclick inside your tag  it should be onclick="genrate_Click1" Then it will take the action.

```
    <asp:Button ID="genrate" runat="server" Text="Genrate passwords" onclick="genrate_Click1"  />
</Content>
```